# Proving Convergence in Probability from Convergence in Every State

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $(X_n)$ be a random sequence and $X,Z$ be two random variables. I need to prove a proposition of the following form:

**Proposition 1**: If $X_n\to X$ in probability, then there exist a random sequence $(Y_n)$ such that $X_n Y_n\to Z$ in probability.

Suppose that I have proven the following proposition for any state $\omega\in\Omega$:

**Proposition 2** : If $X_n(\omega)\to X(\omega)$, then there exist a nonrandom scalar sequence $(y_n)$ such that $X_n(\omega) y_n\to Z(\omega)$.

**Question**: Can I show that proposition 2 implies proposition 1?

My idea is to use the following fact: $X_n$ converges to $X$ in probability if and only if every subsequence of $X_n$ has a sub-subsequence that converges to $X$ almost surely.

The problem is that I don't know how to define $(Y_n)$ in terms of $y_n$ (state by state) to make it work. Any idea is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The choice $Y_n=1$ makes Proposition 1) obvious.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Yes sorry there was a typo the random variable $Z$ is fixed.

Comment: The question hardly make sense to me. Is $Z$ specified in advance? In that case we see that Proposition 1) is false by taking $X=X_n=0$. Otherwise the proposition is obvious: take $Z=X$ and $Y_n=1$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Yes the random variables $(X_n),X,Z$ are fixed. See my new edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is badly stated but here the answer to your question based on the corrections suggested in your comments:

Just define $Y_n(\omega)=\frac {Z(\omega)} {X_n(\omega)}$ if $X_n(\omega) \neq 0$ and $0$ otherwise. Then $Y_n$'s are random variables. Note that if $X_n(\omega)=0$ for infintely many values of $n$ the $Z(\omega)=0$ so $X_n Y_n \to Z$ at such points. At other points $X_nY_n=Z$ after some stage. So we actually have $X_nY_n \to Z$ almost surely!

Comment: @KavidRamaMurthy But you can't just pick any $X_n$, $X$ and $Z$. These random variables are already specified.

Comment: @Alphie If a theorem is true in general it must be true in any special case. What happens if the sequence $(X_n)$ given to you is the zero sequence? Aren't you wasting your time trying to find your $Y_n$'s?

Comment: @KavidRamaMurthy For sure proposition 1 doesn't hold generally. I have shown proposition 2 for a specific choice of $X_n$,$X$ and $Z$ and I want to show proposition 1 from this.

Comment: Your logic is flawed and the result is badly stated. **Inside the first proposition** say that the random variables are assume to satisfy the conclusion of the second proposition.

Comment: @KavidRamaMurthy Fix $X_n,X,Z$. I want to show that Proposition 2 implies Proposition 1. Your example doesn't satisfy proposition 2 so it is not a counterexample.

Comment: @Alphie I have edited my answer. BTW yo u should use the term 'Condition' instead of 'Proposition'. You cannot call either of these as propositions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I edited my post. Hope it is clearer now. Why can't I call these propositions?

Comment: @Alphie A sentence like $f(x) \geq 0$ is a condition on $x$ and $f$. If you call it  a proposition you are saying that the inequality always holds: for all $x$ and for all $f$. A theorem or  a proposition can never be false but conditions may or may not be satisfied.